# AJAX calling PHP file reloads the page, but theoretically correct?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

Here is a skeleton of my code.

```
<?php

if(!isset(get)){
   header("Location: newPage");
} else {
   echo "data";
}

<body>
   <button onclick="callAjax(a,b)"></button>
</body>
<script>
function callAjax(a,b) {

   $.ajax( url:'pagea.php',type:'',data:'',success: function(){alert('success')})

}
</script>
```

This page is called by another page with a get parameter, hence, if there is no get value, it will be redirected to "newPage".
One of the button in this page should call a javascript function onclick.  That function executes the ajax call, and I'm getting 'success' message box too.  But after that, the page gets redirected to "newPage".  My understanding was, after ajax-call the control should come back to the button, where the function was invoked without reloading this page.  But looks like this page is reloaded and routed to "newPage" due to absence of get parameter.

I want to see the same page after completion of function callAjax with the get values as passed initially.  Can somebody guide me what is wrong here?

Thank you.

Comment: `<button type="button" onclick="callAjax(a,b)"></button>`

Comment: Thanks Rayon.  The quotes are in place in my actual program.  As mentioned this is just a skeleton of my program.  Will edit it now.

Comment: `if(!isset(get)){` looks fisshy. isn't it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your time in analyzing this code.  The error was with the  tag, as the browser considers as a submit action and reloads the page.  When this was replaced by `<input type=button>`, the error was resolved, therefore there was no reload upon ajax call.

Thanks again for all your efforts.

Comment: There's no `<form>` in the question, so for the code provided that can't be the reason.

Comment: Its true @Quentin that there is no <form> in my code.  But the only change in my code to make it avoid reload was replacing <button> with <input type='button'>.  and yes, it worked for me.

Comment: That can't make a difference unless there is a form.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, there are flaws in this code. Especially `isset(get)`, the lack of closing `<?php` bracket etc.

This code should not be working as is. And even if it does, an AJAX call should **NOT** reload the page in that case.

It would help if you could provide the entire source code.

I wrote this code to try to reproduce your problem :

```
<?php

if(!isset($_GET['test'])){
   header("Location: newPage.php");
} else {
   echo "data";
}
?>

<body>
   <button type="button" onclick="callAjax(1,2)">Click me</button>
</body>
<script   src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.0.0.min.js"   integrity="sha256-JmvOoLtYsmqlsWxa7mDSLMwa6dZ9rrIdtrrVYRnDRH0="   crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script>
function callAjax(a,b) {

   $.ajax({
      url: 'get.php',
      data: {},
      success: function () { alert('success'); }
   })

}
</script>
```

I get redirected when I don't provide the `test` parameter in the URL, but not when clicking the button, even when the alert shows up.

Comment: Thanks for your effort Hugo!  My problem was resolved.  Please check my answer post.  I will try to keep my skeleton example code clean when posting in future.  Thanks for mentioning the errors.